# Добавление элементов по кнопке, а также добавление фигур на сцену three js и JS

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

я сейчас делаю проект для школы, и мне необходимо узнать, как по кнопке добавить вот такой элемент:

```css
.control {
  z-index: 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange1" step="0.01">.м</p>
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange2" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange3" step="0.01">.м</p>
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange4" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange5" step="0.01">.м</p>
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange6" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange7" step="0.01">.м</p>
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange8" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange9" step="0.01">.м</p>
  <p><input type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange10" step="0.01"><input type="number" min="-50" max="50" value="0" class="slider1" id="myRange11" step="0.01">.м</p>
</div>
```

а также, знаете ведь можно добавлять 3д модели в canvas, так вот, мне нужно чтобы по той же кнопке добавлялась модель MTLoader типо add.scene(MTLoader) и всё это по одной кнопке, пж напишите код люди добрые)))
кстати, добавление элементов должно быть по id, так, к слову)

Comment: То есть надо, чтобы вам за вас сделали вашу работу.

Comment: ахах, пффф, я уже допёр до многого, сейчас крч у меня осталась проблема только с кнопкой, надо добавить только control этот

Comment: Ну, тогда вешайте обработчик события на кнопку через .addEventListener() и добавляйте контрол оттуда.

Comment: а можете напомнить, какая функция добавляет как раз таки тот самый класс control

Comment: только не пойму при чём здесь метка three, в общем так или нет ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzGRBWg